# Scrapy: Can someone tell me why this code does not let me scrape the subsequent pages?

Tags: python, scrapy

I'm a beginner learning how to webscrape using Scrapy in Python. Can someone point out what's wrong? My goal is to scrape all the subsequent pages.

```
from indeed.items import IndeedItem
import scrapy

class IndeedSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "ind"
    allowed_domains = ["https://www.indeed.com"]
    start_urls = ['https://www.indeed.com/jobs?q=analytics+intern&start=']

    def parse(self, response):
        job_card = response.css('.jobsearch-SerpJobCard')
        for job in job_card:
            item = IndeedItem()

            job_title = job.css('.jobtitle::attr(title)').extract()
            company_name = job.css('.company .turnstileLink::text').extract()
            if not company_name:
                company_name = job.css('span.company::text').extract()

            item['job_title'] = job_title
            item['company_name'] = company_name
            yield item

        next_page_extension = response.css('ul.pagination-list a::attr(href)').get()
        if next_page_extension is not None:
            next_page = response.urljoin(next_page_extension)
            yield scrapy.Request(next_page, callback=self.parse)
```

Comment: Hi! We need more details! What is going wrong? Do it run and not give you the output you expect, or does it report some error?

Comment: You have two problems. First, `allowed_domains` shouldn't include `"https://www."` (see [here](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html#scrapy.spiders.Spider.allowed_domains)). Second, your `next_page_extension` is always picking the first item in the navigation. For the second page this sends `scrapy` back to page 1, which it will filter as a duplicate request.

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks pretty good overall, but I can see two issues with it:

1 - The `allowed_domains` property expects us to provide a domain only, not a full URL. Running it as is, you might see something like this in your logs:

```
2021-04-28 21:10:55 [scrapy.spidermiddlewares.offsite] DEBUG: Filtered offsite request to 'www.indeed.com': <GET https://www.indeed.com/jobs?q=analytics+intern&start=10>
```

That means Scrapy is ignoring that request, as it doesn't meet the allowed domains. To fix that, use simply:

```py
allowed_domains = ["indeed.com"]
```

([more about it](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html#scrapy.spiders.Spider.allowed_domains))

2 - The selector you're using for the pagination will match always the first link from the pagination widget. You could try using `.getall()` instead, or get the anchor marked as "Next". Eg:

```
next_page_extension = response.css(
    'ul.pagination-list a[aria-label=Next]::attr(href)'
).get()
```

Answer (score -1):

The content on that site is dynamically generated using JavaScript. `Scrapy` alone doesn't handle JavaScript. You'd need something like `Selenium` + `Scrapy`, [`Splash` + `Scrapy`](https://github.com/scrapy-plugins/scrapy-splash), as [`Scrapy` docs suggest](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/dynamic-content.html#selecting-dynamically-loaded-content), or [other means](http://theautomatic.net/2019/01/19/scraping-data-from-javascript-webpage-python/). `Selenium` is more beginner friendly and there plenty of tutorials on how to use it with `Scrapy`

Comment: In this case the data that is wanted can be obtained with `scrapy`. Disable javascript in your browser and you'll see the information is still there.

Comment: You're right. Skipped that first step and went straight to overkill ️

Comment: That's not true in this case. The pagination links are present in the pages HTML.